# Cannot convert Gray to BGR in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

Following is a snippet of a simple code to convert a grayscale image to RGB using `cvCvtColor` function in OpenCV.

```
input = cvLoadImage("test.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
output = cvCreateImage(cvSize(input->width, input->height), 8, 3);
cvCvtColor(input, output, CV_GRAY2BGR);
cvSaveImage("output.jpg", output);
```

Where test.jpg is a grayscale image.

But it doesn`t seem to be working properly, because output.jpg i.e the final output also is grayscale, same as the input itself. Why so ?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: `But it doesn't seem to be working properly, because output.jpg i.e the final output also is grayscale, same as the input itself. Why so ?` If input is grayscale, than output is also grayscale. It's logically. What did you expect to see? Colored image?

Comment: But I have loaded the image in grayscale and I want to convert it to RGB, same as we sometimes convert a colored image to grayscale.

Comment: What result do you expect? An image with three channels (RGB) instead of only one? Or actually a colored version of the image? (where e.g. the apple that was gray before is now green)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you misunderstand cvCvtColor. `cvCvtColor(input, output, CV_GRAY2BGR);` will change single channel image to 3-channel image. But if you look at the image, it will still look like a gray image because, for example, a gray pixel of 154 has been converted to RGB(154,154,154).

When you convert color image to gray image, all color information will be gone and not recoverable. Therefore you can't really make a gray image to visibly color image without additional information and corresponding operations.

Comment: For future readers, `cvCvtColor`  is `cvtColor` in C++ versions of openCV.